# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION while printing pdfs

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, printing

Some (~4 of many) of our customers have the problem that while trying to print some documents (pdfs) with our software that the application crashes without any exception. The problem occurs only on windows and I can't find any coherences.

All in all it's a very curious bug.

Here is a part of the crash log with enabled dump:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7729fe05, pid=6768, tid=0x00002270
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_212-b04) (build 1.8.0_212-1-ojdkbuild-debug-b04)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (25.212-b04-debug mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x4fe05]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Failed to create file for dumping
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x565ea000):  JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8816, stack(0x011c0000,0x01210000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x00570068

Registers:
EAX=0x00570068, EBX=0x013cdba0, ECX=0x00570064, EDX=0x00eb6000
ESP=0x0120f1e0, EBP=0x0120f1e4, ESI=0x00570064, EDI=0x014095f0
EIP=0x7729fe05, EFLAGS=0x00010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0120f1e0)
0x0120f1e0:   00000001 0120f210 753af30c 00570064
0x0120f1f0:   dd5fb2cd 06211b9e 00210000 013cdba0
0x0120f200:   0057005c 0120f2ec 753df687 ffffffff
0x0120f210:   0120f2a0 76b86cbe 014095f0 013b5f7c
0x0120f220:   06211b9e 0000000a 00000000 00000000
0x0120f230:   00000000 00000000 565ea000 06211b9e
0x0120f240:   5f44fbc0 00000080 038a0029 00000000
0x0120f250:   ff061b9e ffffffff 00001a70 00010621 

Instructions: (pc=0x7729fe05)
0x7729fde5:   cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 8b ff 55 8b ec
0x7729fdf5:   83 e4 f8 8b 4d 08 64 8b 15 18 00 00 00 8d 41 04
0x7729fe05:   f0 0f ba 30 00 73 15 8b 42 24 89 41 0c 33 c0 c7
0x7729fe15:   41 08 01 00 00 00 8b e5 5d c2 04 00 8b 41 0c 3b 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00570068 is an unknown value
EBX=0x013cdba0 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00570064 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00eb6000 is an unknown value
ESP=0x0120f1e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x565ea000
EBP=0x0120f1e4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x565ea000
ESI=0x00570064 is an unknown value
EDI=0x014095f0 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x011c0000,0x01210000],  sp=0x0120f1e0,  free space=316k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x4fe05]
C  [gdi32full.dll+0x8f30c]
C  [GDI32.dll+0x6cbe]
C  [GDI32.dll+0x6984]
C  [awt.dll+0x10422a]  DeletePrintDC+0x8a
C  [awt.dll+0x10412e]  Java_sun_awt_windows_WPrinterJob_deleteDC+0x3e
j  sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob.deleteDC(JJJ)V+0
j  sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob.access$000(JJJ)V+4
j  sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob$HandleRecord.dispose()V+12
j  sun.java2d.Disposer.run()V+26
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x2b75bb]  JavaCalls::call_helper+0x48b
V  [jvm.dll+0x4058fc]  os::os_exception_wrapper+0xac
V  [jvm.dll+0x2b7122]  JavaCalls::call+0x52
V  [jvm.dll+0x2b6ad1]  JavaCalls::call_virtual+0x111
V  [jvm.dll+0x2b6b53]  JavaCalls::call_virtual+0x43
V  [jvm.dll+0x22f892]  thread_entry+0x62
V  [jvm.dll+0x2f0d8b]  JavaThread::thread_main_inner+0xcb
V  [jvm.dll+0x2f0ca7]  JavaThread::run+0x117
V  [jvm.dll+0x3709cc]  java_start+0xdc
C  [MSVCR100.dll+0x5c556]
C  [MSVCR100.dll+0x5c600]
C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x20419]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x6662d]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x665fd]

[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xe0000000]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob.deleteDC(JJJ)V+0
j  sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob.access$000(JJJ)V+4
j  sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob$HandleRecord.dispose()V+12
j  sun.java2d.Disposer.run()V+26
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Here is a part of the analyzed crash dump:

```
FAULTING_IP: 
ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+15
7729fe05 f00fba3000      lock btr dword ptr [eax],0

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  0120eeac -- (.exr 0x120eeac)
ExceptionAddress: 7729fe05 (ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x00000015)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000001
   Parameter[1]: 00570068
Attempt to write to address 00570068

FAULTING_THREAD:  00002270

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_WRITE

PROCESS_NAME:  app.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {AUSNAHME}  Haltepunkt  Im Quellprogramm wurde ein Haltepunkt erreicht.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - Mindestens ein Argument ist ung ltig.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80000003

WATSON_BKT_PROCSTAMP:  5c6fb37d

WATSON_BKT_PROCVER:  1.6.2.0

PROCESS_VER_PRODUCT:  App

WATSON_BKT_MODULE:  ntdll.dll

WATSON_BKT_MODSTAMP:  1ddde673

WATSON_BKT_MODOFFSET:  7076c

WATSON_BKT_MODVER:  10.0.17763.475

MODULE_VER_PRODUCT:  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.17763.475 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-GNESREK

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  05-28-2019 10:00:20.0923

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.18869.1002 amd64fre

CONTEXT:  0120eefc -- (.cxr 0x120eefc)
eax=00570068 ebx=013cdba0 ecx=00570064 edx=00eb6000 esi=00570064 edi=014095f0
eip=7729fe05 esp=0120f1e0 ebp=0120f1e4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x15:
7729fe05 f00fba3000      lock btr dword ptr [eax],0   ds:002b:00570068=????????
Resetting default scope

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
gdi32full!DocumentEventEx+3c
753af30c ff7524          push    dword ptr [ebp+24h]

WRITE_ADDRESS:  00570068 

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 753af30c to 7729fe05

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  e10796f1c19359a1b26a09ff8272ad85c58be40e

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  393c326dee17d593e2102a54d7e9713f31e3e91d

OS_LOCALE:  DEU

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_WRITE_STRING_DEREFERENCE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_FAULT

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 

    ID:     [0n313]
    Type:   [@ACCESS_VIOLATION]
    Class:  Addendum
    Scope:  BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Omit
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [0x1a70]
    TID:    [0x2270]
    Frame:  [0] : ntdll!NtTerminateProcess

    ID:     [0n286]
    Type:   [INVALID_POINTER_WRITE]
    Class:  Primary
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [0x1a70]
    TID:    [0x2270]
    Frame:  [0] : ntdll!NtTerminateProcess

    ID:     [0n184]
    Type:   [STRING_DEREFERENCE]
    Class:  Primary
    Scope:  BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [0x1a70]
    TID:    [0x2270]
    Frame:  [0] : ntdll!NtTerminateProcess

    ID:     [0n97]
    Type:   [@SHUTDOWN]
    Class:  Addendum
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Omit
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [0x1a70]
    TID:    [0x2270]
    Frame:  [0] : ntdll!NtTerminateProcess

STACK_TEXT:  
0120f1e0 7729fe05 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x15
0120f1ec 753af30c gdi32full!DocumentEventEx+0x3c
0120f218 76b86cbe GDI32!InternalDeleteDC+0x30e
0120f2a8 76b86984 GDI32!DeleteDC+0x14
0120f2bc 6ff6422a awt!DeletePrintDC+0x8a
0120f2d4 6ff6412e awt!Java_sun_awt_windows_WPrinterJob_deleteDC+0x3e
0120f300 02e2263d unknown!unknown+0x0
0120f430 02e104fa unknown!unknown+0x0
0120f438 716173f8 jvm!methodHandle::~methodHandle+0x18
1489d1b8 54bddd78 unknown!unknown+0x0
1489d1bc 565ea000 unknown!unknown+0x0
```

Here are some crash logs from other computers without enabled crash dump:

[pastebin1](https://pastebin.com/RGYTTF8q)

[pastebin2](https://pastebin.com/ik3m4cHe)

[pastebin3](https://pastebin.com/5zYwbK6p)

[pastebin4](https://pastebin.com/eQKtGG5f)

I can add some more if you want.

Comment: Are you the vendor for `com.gnostice.pdfone`?  If not, I suggest that you contact the vendor!

Comment: No we are not the developers of this pdf library. I wasn't sure if it's only with this library. I will check it and ask the developers of this library. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is *most likely* due to something that the PDF library is doing ... causing the DLL to do bad things that cause the JVM to crash.  Why it happens only on a specific printer is a bit mysterious.  It could be something to do with printer drivers ... I guess.  The vendor should know more.   (In general, when the vendor provides you with obfuscated code, you pretty much have to rely on *them* for support!)

Comment: As I already said. You have two printers in network which exactly the same. same model, same driver, same configuration. On one printer it works on the other not. Some minutes ago I got the response from one of our customers that they have the same problem with Apache PDFBox selected as printing library. (we included Gnostice PDFOne and Apache PDFBox as printing plugin in our application). Bit more curious, sometimes it works two times and then it crashes again or it starts crashing on another document. I can't find any similarity. I will ask Gnostice for more information on PDFOne

Comment: *"As I already said."* - Maybe, but I'm afraid your English is a bit difficult for me to understand.

Comment: And besides, our conclusions are NOT incompatible.  It could be that the printer driver has *non-deterministic* behavior ...

Comment: I'm not a native speaker so it's hard to explain such exceptions sometimes. I contacted the developers of gnostice pdfone and waiting for a response now. The curious with Apache PDFBox is that there is no crash log generated.

Comment: On two systems we don't get it to work. Tried the software in x64, disabled uac for testing, tried running with administrator rights and tried latest java (11.0.2). But it crashes again and again. In most cases there is no hs_err_pid created. It's not always while printing a document. Sometimes it crashes without doing anything except some logging.